# A tree builder without a root node in Symfony 4.2

Tags: symfony, configuration, upgrade, symfony4

I upgraded my Symfony project from 4.1 to 4.2 and get this notice 12 times in profiler:

> A tree builder without a root node is deprecated since Symfony 4.2 and
>   will not be supported anymore in 5.0.

and the trace of the log is:

```
{▼
  /home/user/foo/bar/project/vendor/symfony/config/Definition/Builder/TreeBuilder.php:30 {▼
    › if (null === $name) {
    ›     @trigger_error('A tree builder without a root node is deprecated since Symfony 4.2 and will not be supported anymore in 5.0.', E_USER_DEPRECATED);
    › } else {
  }
  /home/user/foo/bar/project/vendor/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php:32 {▼
    › {
    ›     $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
    ›     $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('sensio_framework_extra', 'array');
  }
}
```

how to fix this?

Comment: `vendor/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php` needs to be updated in this way - https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/27476/files#diff-f79a519f22ba1864ef38a1b3468e9ed4
It is probably forgotten when this deprecation was added

Comment: Just did an update to Symfony 4.2.1 and my 23 tree builder deprecation notices were reduced to just one: the maker-bundle.  And since I don't use it I commented it out in bundles.php and viola, no more annoying depreciation notices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is already be fixed in the sensio/framework-extra-bundle: 
https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/issues/593

You have to wait for the next update (higher 5.2.2).

Comment: Good catch, David!

Comment: The doctrine bundle also generates the same deprecation notice.  I have not checked to see if an issue has been filed but it is another bundle that needs a slight tweak.  Just one of the hazards of being an early adopter.

Comment: SunCat\MobileDetectBundle also